# ios push notification observer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, observer-pattern

I'm using push notification in my app and I have implemented the following method, called once a notification is received:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
// My code...
}
```

I would like to move the definition of this method in another class.
I was trying to add an observer like the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                 selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground)                                name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                 object:myObject];
```

But there is no a key/name ( UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification ) to observe push notification.

Can I attack the problem in a different way? Maybe I can use some AOP library for objective-c.

Note:With PushKit it is possible to set the relative delegate during the registration of the notification. With 'default' notification there is no way to set a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add observer like this for when app goes in background :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(methodName)name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```